# What does 『なのよさ』 at the end of a sentence mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions, slang, dialects, kansai-ben

I am currently playing a Visual Novel, and there's a character who ends all of her sentences with that 『なのよさ』(This is 蒔菜{まきな} from the Grisaia VN series). From what I understood that has to do with 関西方言{かんさいほうげん}　(Kansai dialect), but I can't find anything on the Internet concerning that...

Comment: Japanese Wikipedia has a section in their article on 語尾【ごび】 titled 「キャラ語尾」 that you might like to take a look at: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%AA%9E%E5%B0%BE#.E3.82.AD.E3.83.A3.E3.83.A9.E8.AA.9E.E5.B0.BE; see also [役割語【やくわりご】](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BD%B9%E5%89%B2%E8%AA%9E).

Comment: If that were a common sentence-ending, you would need to wonder why the other characters do not use it at least once in a while.  Never heard 「なのよさ」 anywhere in Japan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are four main parts to consider:

1. な (the form of the copula before の<s>だ</s>)
2. の<strike>だ</strike> (which has a wide range of uses and is highly context-dependent)
3. よ (an interactional particle)
4. さ (another interactional particle)

The last three are all **highly context dependent**.  But the character ends **all** of their sentences with them, right?  They just pile them all on with no regard for context or meaning.

**So the meaning doesn't really matter.**

This is just a fictional character who's been given a special way of speaking that makes them stand out.  They aren't really using なの or よ or さ the way they're typically used in Japanese.  This sort of thing is pretty common in fiction; I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: 「なんだわさ。」「なのよね。」「なのよ。」「なのさ。」はありますが、「なのよさ。」は不自然ですね・・。方言でも、聞いたことがないです。

Comment: 「なのよさ」っていうとピノコを思い出しますね，そういえば．

Comment: @Yosh ググったら、元は、その「ピノコ」っていうキャラクターのキャラ語尾が最初だったみたいですね。